# Could not open CMIP6 data downloaded from worldclim (v 2.1)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geotiff-tiff

I've downloaded **CMIP6 bioclimatic variables** (one multiband tif file containing all 19 bioclimatic variables as layers) from **worldclim (version 2.1)**. Some of the files opened normally in **ArcGIS 10.8**, while others did not. For instance, when I try to open the file **"wc2.1_30s_bioc_MIROC6_ssp126_2041-2060.tif"**, the latter is visible in the table of contents but nothing is displayed. I've tried **rebuilding pyramids** with every possible combination (resamling technique x compression type) and tried also **calculating statistics**, but I got nothing.
I noticed that after calculating statistics, the **Min** and **Max** values of the statistics of the first band are shown as **anormally very big values**, while there are no values for the rest of bands "Statistics have not been calculated".
I tried opening the same files with other softwares (QGIS, ENVI), in other PCs but without success.

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about issues with its quality is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem opening 2081-2100 tifs in QGIS. Some of the models worked, including wc2.1_30s_bioc_MIROC6_ssp585_2081-2100, but more than half, including wc2.1_30s_bioc_MIROC-ES2L_ssp585_2081-2100, only contained bands with 'no data' values. I have re-downloaded the files and consistently the same ones have only no data values in them.