# Download and Data Errors with 5 of WorldCLIM’s CMIP6 Future Climate Data models

Tags: raster, data, error, download, climate

I'm experiencing some data issues specifically for the following WorldCLIM’s CMIP6 Future Climate Data models, available at https://www.worldclim.org/data/cmip6/cmip6_clim30s.html

Data details:

- Climatic Variables: Bioclimatic
- Time Period: 2021-2040
- Shared Socioeconomic Pathways (SSPs): SSP126
- Spatial Resolution: 30 seconds

**Models and issues:**

**A) URL Error: The requested URL was not found on this server**

BCC-CSM2-MR - https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/cmip6/30s/BCC-CSM2-MR/ssp126/wc2.1_30s_bioc_BCC-CSM2-MR_ssp126_2021-2040.tif

**B) Data Error: Downloaded Raster was empty / No Data generated on the map**

ACCESS-CM2 - https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/cmip6/30s/ACCESS-CM2/ssp126/wc2.1_30s_bioc_ACCESS-CM2_ssp126_2021-2040.tif

EC-Earth3-Veg - https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/cmip6/30s/EC-Earth3-Veg/ssp126/wc2.1_30s_bioc_EC-Earth3-Veg_ssp126_2021-2040.tif

FIO-ESM-2-0 - https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/cmip6/30s/FIO-ESM-2-0/ssp126/wc2.1_30s_bioc_FIO-ESM-2-0_ssp126_2021-2040.tif

IPSL-CM6A-LR - https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/cmip6/30s/IPSL-CM6A-LR/ssp126/wc2.1_30s_bioc_IPSL-CM6A-LR_ssp126_2021-2040.tif

Is there a solution to these errors?

Link to another post that is facing similar issues: [Could not open CMIP6 data downloaded from worldclim (v 2.1)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427307/could-not-open-cmip6-data-downloaded-from-worldclim-v-2-1?rq=1)

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about any issues with its quality is at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.